# Django display forms.ValidationError at template

Tags: django, forms, change-password, reset-password

My Django application uses a token based password reset mechanism, but I'm currently not able to display any error message at my template if "user is not None and str(form_token) == str(user.reset_token)" is not given

-> Error if my input is a none existing user:

> File "/app/App_Accounts/views.py", line 280, in reset_password
>
> user = form.save()
>
> File "/app/App_Accounts/forms.py", line 315, in save
>
> user = User.objects.get(user=form_user)
>
> App_Accounts.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not
> exist.

views.py:

```
def reset_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TokenPasswordResetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save() # line 280
  ....
```

forms.py:

```
class TokenPasswordResetForm(forms.Form):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _('Password fields didn’t match, please try again'),
        'user_or_token_mismatch': _('Unable to find user or token match'),
    }
    user = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        strip=False,
    )
    reset_token = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        strip=False
    )

    new_password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("New Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
    )

    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(TokenPasswordResetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['user'].label = 'Username:'
       ...

 
    def save(self, commit=True):
       """Save the new password."""
       form_user = self.cleaned_data.get('user')
       form_token = self.cleaned_data.get('reset_token')
       user = User.objects.get(user=form_user) # line 315
       if user is not None and str(form_token) == str(user.reset_token):
           password = self.cleaned_data["new_password1"]
           user.set_password(password)
           user.reset_token_memorized = False
           user.reset_token = reset_token_generator()
           if commit:
               user.save()
           return user
       raise forms.ValidationError(
           self.error_messages['user_or_token_mismatch'],
           code='user_or_token_mismatch',
       )
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.CharField(verbose_name='Username', unique=True)
...
```

Comment: You should not do validation at the `save` method, but at the `clean` method.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem okay, will try that right away.

Comment: Can you furthermore share the model you are working with? Exactly what is the `user` field?

Comment: user = models.CharField(verbose_name='Username', unique=True)

Comment: @MarkusBreda: can you [edit] the question?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not sure how to decouple the save method properly to def clean or at least it seems to have no effect so far, can you give a solution how this has to look like? Thanks in advance